# IOS/Objective-C: Call regular self method from within class method

Tags: ios, objective-c, class

I have a class method that I am calling the following way:

```
#import myClass.h;

[MYClass classMethod];

In myClass, I have a method as follows:

+(void)classMethod {
NSLog(@"classMethod called");
[self otherMethod];
}

-(void) otherMethod {
NSLog(@"other method called");
}
```

This throws an unknown selector error, however.

My understanding is self means something other than the file in a class method, namely the class itself and I can get rid of that error by changing -otherMethod to +otherMethod.  However, there are actually many methods in the NSObject that get called in sequence so I would rather not have to change everythign to a +.

Is that what you are supposed to do when to call a method from within a class method?  Or is there an alternative to self?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: self is typically treated like an instance of a class, I'm not 100% off the top of my head but it may work if you were calling another class method from a class method. 
If your class method needs to take some action on an instance maybe add a parameter for it to the class method?

Comment: I use self a lot....to get many instance variables and to call numerous methods.  Is there no way to access the file in which the class method sits from within the class?

Comment: If you have a class method that wants to call an instance method, that suggests a deeper design flaw. Just because "there are actually many [instance] methods ... called in sequence" is not a reason to not fix this flaw. Frankly, it's impossible to answer this in the abstract, as the right solution depends upon what these various methods are actually doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the question there is some confusion over at least terminology and the actual issue is not clear. Hopefully some of the following may help.

> My understanding is self means something other than the file in a class method, namely the class itself

The variable `self` *never* means the *file*, it always refers to the object on which the method was called. The difference between class and instance methods is the type of the object on which the method is called.

Your sample class:

```
@implemention MyClass
{
   // any instance variables
}

+ (void)classMethod
{
   NSLog(@"classMethod called");
   [self otherMethod];
}

- (void) otherMethod
{
   NSLog(@"other method called");
}

// ...

@end
```

Defines a *template* from which a *class object* (which has a type which is (eventually) a subclass of the `Class` type), and zero or more *instance objects* (of type `MyClass`), are created. The class object get the class methods, the instance objects get the instance methods and each one gets their own set of the instance variables.

In the code fragment:

```
MyClass *anInstance = [MyClass new];
[anInstance otherMethod];
```

then the value of `anInstance`, a reference to an object of type `MyClass`, is passed to `otherMethod` and made available as the value of `self`. In the code fragment:

```
[MyClass classMethod];
```

the compiler effectively replaces `MyClass` with a reference to the single instance of the `MyClass` class object, an object reference, and passes it to `classMethod` where it is made available as the value of `self`... In other words "calling a class method" is "calling an instance method on the class object" - the mechanism is the same.

The variable `self` never refers to the "file" and provides no way to directly access anything other than members of the object - being the instance or class object - which it references.

In particular `self` within a class method does not provide access to instance methods or variables as they are members of an *instance object* and `self` references the *class object*. To access instance methods or variables anywhere requires an *instance object*.

> Is that what you are supposed to do when to call a method from within a class method? Or is there an alternative to self?

The "alternative" is a reference to an instance object. There are potentially many instances and there is no language defined "default" one which a class method can use. Which should not be surprising as a vital characteristic of an instance is its *identity* - in a typical application there are many arrays (`NSArray`), with different contents, of different types, being using for different purposes, each one distinct from the others i.e. having a unique identity and methods are called on these individuals to pass information to/from that *particular* individual (aka instance).

From your statement it appears what you might be after is something like:

```
+ (void)classMethodUsingInstance:(MyClass *)someInstance
{
   NSLog(@"classMethod called");
   [someInstance otherMethod];
}
```

That is for some reason you want a class method which can interact with a particular instance, so you pass it as an argument. However that raises the question of why this is not just an instance method...

> Is there a better way to run a lot of complex code from a view controller without putting it in the VC? classMethod happens to be a sync operation with a server that uses a lot of properties and a lot of methods. I don't want to put it in the VC that calls the method if possible, because that VC already manages an awful lot... [from a comment]

This comment makes it sound like your `classMethod` and `otherMethod` are in *different* classes, the latter is in your view controller class, the former you don't specify where it is other than "I don't want to put it in the VC". If this is the case the above outline which passes an instance of your VC to a method defined elsewhere is probably what you need. I.e. you have some large complex process which operates on a VC rather than being part of a VC, so you define that process in another class - as instance or class methods as best suits the design - and pass the VC instance to it.

This is not just a standard model but a fundamental one (e.g. think of all the code you write which uses arrays and dictionaries but is not part of arrays or dictionaries!), which raises the question of why you would have a problem and ask the question in the first places... so maybe you are asking something else...

> It can't be an instance method because it needs to be called from a different view controller class. [from a comment]
>
> Perhaps I need to create a property of the class named sharedInstance and then I can access properties and methods of the class using `[self sharedInstance].property` and `[[self sharedInstance] method]`. [from the following comment]

Combined with the previous "not in the VC" comments this now sounds like:

- you wish to call a method `M` on class `A`;
- that method needs to operate on a particular instance of `B`;
- the call should come from a method `N` in a different class `C`; and
- the method `N` does not have a reference to the particular instance of `B` required to pass in it's call to `M`.

Which if correct means yes, you probably want a *shared instance* model for `B`.

Hope that helps a little, and doesn't just confuse!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed answer. I intended my question to be a practical one.  Where do I put code that should ideally be reusable but needs properties to work properly--too many properties to be passed as arguments to a function.   I am trying to avoid the dreaded viewcontroller that ate the world version of MVC where you put all the code in one view controller.  My takeaway from your answer is that the shared Instance approach is the right way to go and, in fact, this is what I got to work.

Answer (score 3):

In an instance method, `self` is a reference to the current instance of the current class. A class method, as its name implies, is called on the class itself, not on an instance, so there is no current instance for `self` to refer to. In this case, `self` refers to the current class.

In other words in a class method invoking `[self otherMethod]` would call another class method called `otherMethod` (i.e. declared with a +). To call an instance method, you need an instance of your object to work on, either one that is passed to your class method or one that is instantiated by your class method itself,  but you still wouldn’t refer to that instance with `self`, you would use the parameter or variable name.

Generally this shouldn’t be an issue. You need to consider the semantics of your object and whether the methods should all be class methods (i.e. they don’t need to operate on a specific instance of your object) or whether they should be instance methods with your class method creating a new instance if required, or perhaps your class method shouldn’t be a class method.

Comment: Is there a way to access instance variables? or properties or do I have to pass them all in as parameters.  I have a lot of them so it would be nice to use the ivars.

Comment: But the properties of which instance?  That is the issue. There could be any number of instances of `MYClass` (Or none) and a class method doesn’t know which one you might be referring to because it doesn’t know anything about those instances

Comment: Understood.  Is there a better way to run a lot of complex code from a view controller without putting it in the VC?  classMethod happens to be a sync operation with a server that uses a lot of properties and a lot of methods.  I don't want to put it in the VC that calls the method if possible, because that VC already manages an awful lot including a separate sync (to a different core data entity.)

Comment: So I would be asking why this is a class method. If it needs access to instance properties then maybe it should be an instance method.  Or maybe this method doesn’t belong in this class; perhaps you need to further decompose your objects. It is hard to say without more detail on the object in question.

Comment: It can't be an instance method because it needs to be called from a different view controller class.  On the other hand, what it manages--syncing of a JSON feed and storing to Core Data as well as uploading local data to a server using JSON-- is sufficiently complex that I can't imagine doing it without access to properties and also breaking up the code into component methods.  Hence my desire to call otherMethod from within the main method myMethod.  I guess you are saying there is no way to break up myMethod or access properties using the class approach.

Comment: Perhaps I need to create a property of the class named sharedInstance and then I can access properties and methods of the class using [self sharedInstance].property and [[self sharedInstance] method].  I will try this out.

Comment: That is a singleton pattern, as suggested in the other, now deleted, answer. That probably isn’t the right approach. If the method needs access to instance properties and methods then it probably shouldn’t be a class method. Having a class method access a singleton instance of its own class is just wrong.

Comment: "because it needs to be called from a different view controller class"  If you have one view controller directly calling methods on another view controller, then you've almost certainly broken MVC. There are some narrow exceptions around delegation and parent-child relationships, but only for setting up the other object; not applying logic and getting results. If you have a view controller method that returns a value, and another VC calls it, that's broken. Move the logic into another object (a singleton, an object you pass around, anything, but not a VC)